# Java Class extends Abstract class but must have static method

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, static-methods, factory

I'm just playing around creating a program. I have an Abstract Class Foo (implements OtherThing), and a Class Bar that extends Foo. I plan on having several other classes that extend Foo and want to make sure they all have Static method.

```
public abstract class Foo implements OtherThing {//....}  

public class Bar extends Foo{  
  public static Map<Enum, List<AnotherEnum> getSomeThingMap(){  
    create someThingMap;  
    someThingMap.put(Enum, List<AnotherEnum>);
    return someThingMap;  
  }  
}
```

I need any class that extends Foo to have this method in order for my Factory that creates the class to work. I can manually add the static method to each class that needs it. Each Bar class will create a slightly different Map. I tried adding the static method to both the Interface class OtherThing and the Abstract class Foo. Any way to do this or am I stuck adding this method to each class that I need to. I know it's not really hard just would prefer to force this method to be there.

Comment: In what scenario is it *necessary* for a class to have a static method?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth e.g when you want to have an instance counter?

Comment: @Andres: That's an internal implementation detail.  There's no way to call a static method in a polymorphic way (unless you include reflection), so what use would it be to enforce that from the interface?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think there are plenty of ways to justify the use of a static method.

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Not as part of a polymorphic interface, though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Agreed and its also not possible. I wasn't sure exactly what you were inferring in your first comment.

Comment: @user3290994 Can you explain a little more about how you envision this static method being used.  What exactly happens to the `Map` returned by the static method?

Comment: The factory I'm creating uses this map to build other clases head, center/left/right torsos, left/right leg/arm. The map contains information on the specifics of them. I'm planing on using Guice for my DI. I'm trying to avoid using setters as once this Bar class is created these specific cannot be changed. The specifics are accessory style information as well as information based off of what size/character type it implements and extends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to inherit static Methods. But it should not be necessary, because you can call the static method from your top level class directly, just make sure they are public.

Just to remember: Static Methods of a Class should not be used to model Object behavior, valid Use Cases for a static method are in general routines that do not manipulate the state of the underlying object. If you are not familiar with object-oriented design, it would be worth having a look, to make your code more maintainable.

I your use case if you want to call a static method from Foo in Bar you can just call Foo.staticMethod() in Bar:

```
public abstract class Foo implements OtherThing {//....}  

public class Bar extends Foo{  
  public static Map<Enum, List<AnotherEnum> getSomeThingMap(){  
    create someThingMap; 

    //Call your static Method from Foo here
    Foo.staticMethod()
    someThingMap.put(Enum, List<AnotherEnum>);
    return someThingMap;  
  }  
}
```

Comment: I thought of that, the only problem is I have several classes like Bar such as Bar_1, Bar_2 Bar_2_1, these are variations/model differences as may have slight differences. Things like max rotation angle of arms, if arms end in a hand with 5 fingers or a claw.

Comment: I'm not trying to inherit a static method with a body I'd like to inherit a static method with an empty body, like how an interface works but it's not possible. I think what I'm trying to do is not possible was hoping that maybe I was missing something or someone had a good idea on how to do it a different way.

Comment: You could create one central static class that holds all your necessary operations, this will  work. Or you try to use generics that handover some behavior to your classes.